# no module named scrapy.spider while crawling using scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I have scrapy code to crawl the websites. My code is as below.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class JustASpider(Spider):
    name = "googlespider"
    allowed_domains=["google.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=search"]


    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        print (sites)
        #for site in sites: (I dont know why you want to loop for extracting the text in the title element)
            #print site.extract()
```

When I run this using `$scrapy crawl test.py` I get error

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
ImportError: No module named 'scrapy.spider'
```

I am trying few other examples as well but getting same error for all.

Comment: you made changes to the file settings.py ?

Comment: settings.py content is                                                                   
```BOT_NAME = 'craigslist_sample'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['craigslist_sample.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'craigslist_sample.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True```

Comment: Create a new project `scrapy startproject googlespider2`. This is the code `import scrapy ;class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):;name = "googles"`......

Comment: Do you have a `scrapy.py` file or a `scrapy` folder containing a `__init__.py` file anywhere in your project?

Comment: No. I don't have any such folder in project. But I have scrapy installed in my system.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
import scrapy


class JustASpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "googlespider"
    allowed_domains=["google.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=search"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        print (sites)
        #for site in sites: (I dont know why you want to loop for extracting the text in the title element)
            #print site.extract()
```